# Get a DIVs parent TD using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I tired the following javascript to fetch a buttons parent TD but i did not find it to work

```
$(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
        alert($(this).closest('span').html());
    });
```

The above code alerts 'undefined', following is the mark up. In this mark up 'editable-submit' is the target. What I need is the javascript should alert the    <td> value which is 'Output Content' in this example.

```
<td>
<span class="xedit editable editable-click editable-open" data-original-title="" title="">
Output Content
</span>
<div class="popover fade top in editable-container editable-popup" style="top: 12px; left: 0px; display: block;">
<div class="arrow" style="left: 23.007246376811597%;">
</div>
<h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;">
</h3>
<div class="popover-content">

  <div>
    <div class="editableform-loading" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <form class="form-inline editableform" style="">
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div>
          <div class="editable-input" style="position: relative;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">
            <span class="editable-clear-x">
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="editable-buttons">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
              </i>

            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
              </i>

            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editable-error-block help-block" style="display: none;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean `Data` in that `td` not selecting actual `td` ? or selecting `td` ?

Comment: `$(this).closest("span")` looks for a `<span>` parent, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, The `span` is not an ancestor of the clicked button so you cannot use closest() directly, you need to find the ancestor `td` element using `closest('td')` then find the `span` child using find() like `find('span')`

```
alert($(this).closest('td').children('span').html());
```

Comment: Perfect. I would like to learn jQuery but I know it can't be done overnight... -_-